# What is "a lifetime's worth" of something?

Tags: meaning

> What started as a lifetime’s worth of conversations about comedy becomes something else entirely.

I don't quite understand "lifetime's worth of".

Answer (score 2):

A "lifetime's worth" here is being used figuratively.

It is hyperbolic. The writer is exagerating for effect.

The meaning is

The conversations that the author is speaking of are so plentiful, that they could fill a lifetime.

The author then goes on to say they became something else entirely. So these copious conversations, somehow took on a different meaning. The sense is that they became more than the substance of their individual parts (just an inordinate series of conversations about comedy) and somehow took on some meaning above and beyond their sheer number.

**Edit: in relation to comments about worth**

"lifetime's worth" is synonymous with "enough to last a lifetime"

'Worth' in this context means, "enough to last"

"enough to last a lifetime".

E.g. 
"I've done 5 weeks worth of excercise today, I'm exhausted!"

Comment: Hi, this sounds very useful but I want to know how the "worth" is used in this case and can you please provide some more examples of such usage of the word. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sentence appears in a blurb describing *Sick in the Head: Conversations about Life and Comedy* by Judd Apatow.   Here is the line in context:

> *Sick in the Head* gathers Apatow's most memorable and revealing conversations into one hilarious, wide-ranging, and incredibly candid collection that spans not only his career, but his entire adult life.   The comedy legends who inspired and shaped him, from Mel Brooks to Steve Martin, the contemporaries he grew up with, from Spike Jonze to Sarah Silverman.   And the brightest stars in comedy today, from Seth Rogen to Amy Schumer.
>
> And along the way, something kind of magical happens: what started as a lifetime's worth of conversations about comedy becomes something else entirely.   It becomes an exploration of creativity, ambition, neediness, generosity, spirituality, and the joy that comes from making people laugh.

Given this context, "a lifetime's worth of conversations about comedy" and the "candid collection [of conversations] that spans . . . his entire adult life" share their referent.   This "lifetime's worth" means all of the (relevant) conversations in which one person participated over the course of his lifetime.   In general, "a lifetime's worth" is enough to fill a lifetime.